# Netbeans ant build error 'unsupported element customize'

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I updated to Netbeans 8.0.1 from 7.0.1 and my java program compiles fine if 'Web Start' is disabled. As soon as 'Web Start' is enabled I get the following error:

```
C:\NetBeansProjects\SearchCriteriaEditor\nbproject\jnlp-impl.xml:480: 
unsupported element customize
```

- in this section of the jnlp-impl.xml file:

  `<target name="-do-jar-jnlp-application" depends="-init-filename,-test-jnlp-type,-init-macrodef-copylibs" if="is.application+mkdist.available">
      <j2seproject3:copylibs manifest="${tmp.manifest.file}">
          <customize>
              <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
          </customize>
      </j2seproject3:copylibs>
      <echo>To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:</echo>
      <property location="${jnlp.dest.dir}/${jnlp.file}" name="jnlp.file.resolved"/>
      <echo>javaws "${jnlp.file.resolved}"</echo>
  </target>`

The fix, as I understand it is to: 'add following to customized junit macro definition:'

```
<attribute default="" name="testmethods"/>
   <element name="customize" optional="true"/>
<customize/>
```

Trouble is I have no idea where that is, nor have I modified my ant file in any way...can anyone give me a bit more information? I assume the fix goes somewhere in the jnlp-impl.xml file; I just have no idea where to put it.

Edit update: added all sections with references to 'copylibs' in the jnlp-impl.xml file-

```
<target name="-test-jnlp-type" depends="-test-jnlp-enabled" if="is.jnlp.enabled">
    <condition property="is.applet">
        <equals arg1="${jnlp.descriptor}" arg2="applet" trim="true"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="is.application">
        <equals arg1="${jnlp.descriptor}" arg2="application" trim="true"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="is.component">
        <equals arg1="${jnlp.descriptor}" arg2="component" trim="true"/>
    </condition>
    <condition property="is.applet+mkdist.available">
        <and>
            <isset property="libs.CopyLibs.classpath"/>
            <istrue value="${is.applet}"/>
        </and>
    </condition>
    <condition property="is.application+mkdist.available">
        <and>
            <isset property="libs.CopyLibs.classpath"/>
            <istrue value="${is.application}"/>
        </and>
    </condition>
    <condition property="is.component+mkdist.available">
        <and>
            <isset property="libs.CopyLibs.classpath"/>
            <istrue value="${is.component}"/>
        </and>
    </condition>
</target>

......

<target name="-do-jar-jnlp-application" depends="-init-filename,-test-jnlp-type,-init-macrodef-copylibs" if="is.application+mkdist.available">
    <j2seproject3:copylibs manifest="${tmp.manifest.file}">
        <customize>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </customize>
    </j2seproject3:copylibs>
    <echo>To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:</echo>
    <property location="${jnlp.dest.dir}/${jnlp.file}" name="jnlp.file.resolved"/>
    <echo>javaws "${jnlp.file.resolved}"</echo>
</target>
<target name="-do-jar-jnlp-component" depends="-test-jnlp-type,-init-macrodef-copylibs" if="is.component+mkdist.available">
    <j2seproject3:copylibs manifest="${tmp.manifest.file}"/>
</target>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<j2seproject3:copylibs` invokes the macrodef `copylibs` with the namespace prefix `j2seproject3`. There should be a place in the buildfile where the `copylibs` macro is defined, in a way similar (but not necessarily exact) to:

```
<macrodef name="copylibs" uri="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3">
```

The above line should logically exist inside the `-init-macrodef-copylibs` target, and this is where the `customize` element should be defined as well. Below is the snippet based on a sample NetBeans project I have. The content will probably not match exactly the one you have, so take my answer with a grain of salt:

```
<macrodef name="copylibs" uri="http://www.netbeans.org/ns/j2se-project/3">
    ... <!-- some attributes may be defined here first -->
    <element name="customize" optional="true"/>  <!-- customize should be defined here -->
    <sequential>
        ...
        <!-- somewhere in the macrodef -->
        <copylibs compress="${jar.compress}" index="${jar.index}" jarfile="${dist.jar}" manifest="${manifest.file}" runtimeclasspath="${run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${build.classes.dir}"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${jar.classpath}"/>
                <customize/>    <!-- this is where customize is used -->  
            </manifest>
         </copylibs>
         ...
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Comment: Hi manouti, sorry to be a pain.. There is no macrodef for copylibs. I have added all references to copylibs in the nlp-impl.xml to the original question. Do I need to add this to the file?

Comment: @Robbie62 For sure there exists a definition for `copylibs` somewhere. Could it be in a different Ant buildfile that is imported by `jnlp-impl.xml`?

Comment: Hi manouti, yes, there is another build file that I completely forgot about. I'm doing a Google Startup challenge at the moment so I won't be able to get back to it till a couple of days time.

Comment: After four years of working on this thing, I think burnout maybe setting in. Classic case of global search and replace, replacing things it shouldn't. Australians spell customize as "customise" so when I re-enabled webstart and it used an entry with "customize' in it, it couldn't find the original definition because the glbal search had changed it. Thank you manouti, at least you got me looking in the right place...I am exceedingly grateful.